# Accessing the Store in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a project in react and redux with immutablejs.  It looks like this:

The Page looks like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    content: state.content
 }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(thunks, dispatch)
    };
}


class ConnectedConnect extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
    const { actions } = this.props
    actions.retrieveContent();
    console.log(this.props.content)
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header heading="Demo Heading" colour="orange" disableAnimation={false} />

        </div >
    );
    }
}

`const Content = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)`(ConnectedConnect);

export default Content
```

The api:

```
export function viewContent() {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8080/watchlist/content",
        {
            method: "GET",

        }).then(function (response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            // Read the response as json.)
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
        })

}
```

The actions:

```
export function contentSuccess(retrieveContentWasSuccessful) {
    return { type: types.RETRIEVE_CONTENT_SUCCESS, contentSuccess };
}

export function retrieveContent() {
    // make async call to api, handle promise, dispatch action when promise is resolved
    return function (dispatch) {
        return viewContent().then(retrieveContentWasSuccessful => {
            dispatch(contentSuccess(retrieveContentWasSuccessful));
        }).catch(error => {
            throw (error);
        });
    };
}
```

The reducer:

```
export function contentReducer(state = fromJS({}), action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.RETRIEVE_CONTENT_SUCCESS:
            return state.merge(action.content)
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

The store itself is like this:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory()
const store = createStore(
    connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
    applyMiddleware(
        routerMiddleware(history),
        thunkMiddleware
    )
);

export { store, history };
```

The api is successfully called.  However I can't seem to actually access the response in the store!  Grateful for any help with this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Think you want to pass `retrieveContentWasSuccessful` here instead of `contentSuccess`:

```
export function contentSuccess(retrieveContentWasSuccessful) {
    return { type: types.RETRIEVE_CONTENT_SUCCESS, retrieveContentWasSuccessful };
}
```